# localization of dates in LightweightCharts

Tags: localization, lightweight-charts

I´m using LightweightCharts from Tradingview to display exchange rates. The problem is I don't know how to change the language of the months in the bottom part of the chart.

Have a look at
 [this graph of oil in Polish.](https://forbino.com/pl/surowce/olej-opalowy/)

[image]
What I have found is that the language of the graph should change based on the language of the visitors' browser. But it does not work. I have tried it, it still shows the months in Czech.

Could you please help with the settings?